# I am randomly modifying a HSV colour but the colour is not what it's supposed to be

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I apologise for the bad wording of the title

my program works by taking a base colour, and then modifying the saturation and value and saving that colour to a list, resulting is a list of similar colours

however when my program uses these colours to generate an image, the generated colours are darker and less saturated than they should be

[here is an image to better explain my point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwRzN.png)

the colour on the left is the base colour, the middle colour is what the modified colour is supposed to look like and the right colour is what the colour actually looks like

here is a different piece of code that produces the same  :

```
import random
from PIL import Image



basecol = (24, 78, 45) # the base colour
size = (16, 16) # size of the texture

colnum = random.randint(7, 15) # number of different colours to generate


colours = [basecol]
for col in range(colnum):
    satchange = random.randint(-30, 30)
    valchange = random.randint(-30, 30)
    
    news = basecol[1]+satchange
    newv = basecol[2]+valchange
    
    
    newcol = (basecol[0], news, newv)
    
    colours.append(newcol)
    print(newcol)



woodTex = Image.new("HSV", size)


for x in range(size[0]):
    for y in range(size[1]):
        
        randcol = random.choice(colours)
        woodTex.putpixel((x, y), randcol)


woodTex = woodTex.convert("RGB")
woodTex.save("Wood Texture.png")
```

I have also produced some more simple code that has the same problem :

```
from PIL import Image


xsize = 100
ysize = 100

new = Image.new("HSV", (xsize, ysize))
HSVcol = (24, 78, 44)
RGBcol = (114, 61, 25)

for x in range(xsize):
    for y in range(ysize):
        
        new.putpixel((x, y), HSVcol)
        

new = new.convert("RGB")

new.save("test.png")
```

Comment: Please try to make your code a *"Minimal Complete Verifiable Example"* https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example Currently there are no `import` statements and too many parts missing to make it runnable. Thank you.

Comment: And what are the hsv values of all three colors? You are changing the base color randomly, so how do you know what the output is supposed to be? Unless of course it is outside the limits you set with `random.randint(-30,30)`. Is that the case?

Comment: @Ronald to attain the example image, I inputted a base colour and edited the program so that only one colour is generated, I then printed out the HSV values of that colour. Then I produced that colour manually in an image editing application and, since only one colour had been generated, the output image was only one colour - the colour to the right my example image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the problem

as far as I know, for HSV colours the Hue has a range of 360, and Saturation & Value have a range of 100

but in PIL Hue, Saturation and Value all have a range of 255

so to fix the distorted colours I just added this line

```
basecol = (round(basecol[0]/360*255), round(basecol[1]/100*255), round(basecol[2]/100*255))
```